# Dagger component: error: cannot find symbol kotlin classes

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger

Generated component of dagger couldn't find symbol of the kotlin classes even if there is no read lines on this component.

> Task :app:compileStagingDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

```
\app\build\generated\source\kapt\stagingDebug\...\DaggerAppComponent.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
import com...features.Main.splash_screen.SplashScreenActivity;
                                                                     ^
symbol:   class SplashScreenActivity
location: package com...features.Main.splash_screen
```

**When I type the code in java it runs successfully and this issue only happens in windows. It doesn't appear in mac or **linux**.**

```
interface ISplashScreen  : IView {
    fun gotoMainScreen()
}

@Module
abstract class SplashModule {
    @Binds
    abstract fun provideISplash(splashScreenActivity: SplashScreenActivity): ISplashScreen
}


class SplashScreenActivity : BaseActivity<SplashScreenPresenter>(), ISplashScreen {

    @Inject
    lateinit var splashScreenPresenter: SplashScreenPresenter

    override fun gotoMainScreen() {
        Navigator.goToMainScreen(context)
    }

    override fun onCreateInit(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    }

    override fun getLayout(): Int = R.layout.activity_splash

    override fun initPresenter(): SplashScreenPresenter = splashScreenPresenter
}

class SplashScreenPresenter @Inject constructor(view: ISplashScreen,
                                                environment: PresenterEnvironment)
    : BasePresenter<ISplashScreen>(view, environment) {

    // TODO : load project data by API
    @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    override fun startLogic(savedInstance: Bundle?) {
        super.startLogic(savedInstance)
        Completable.timer(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .compose(getDestroyIoTransformer<Unit>())
                .subscribe {
                    view.gotoMainScreen()
                }
    }
}

@Module
public abstract class ActivityModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = SplashModule.class)
    abstract SplashScreenActivity bindSplashScreenActivity();

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = { CartFragmentProvider.class, CategoryFragmentProvider.class})
    abstract MainActivity bindMainActivity();
}

//Gradle

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-platform-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.23.1"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.23.1"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.23.1"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.23.1"
```

```
...\app\build\generated\source\kapt\stagingDebug\com\...\common\di\components\DaggerAppComponent.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
import com....features.Main.splash_screen.SplashScreenActivity;
                                                                     ^
  symbol:   class SplashScreenActivity
  location: package com....features.Main.splash_screen
...\app\build\generated\source\kapt\stagingDebug\com\...\common\di\components\DaggerAppComponent.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
import com....features.Main.splash_screen.SplashScreenPresenter;
                                                                     ^
  symbol:   class SplashScreenPresenter
  location: package com....features.Main.splash_screen
...\app\build\generated\source\kapt\stagingDebug\com\...\common\di\modules\ActivityModule_BindSplashScreenActivity.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
import com....features.Main.splash_screen.SplashModule;
                                                                     ^
  symbol:   class SplashModule
  location: package com....features.Main.splash_screen
...\app\build\generated\source\kapt\stagingDebug\com\...\common\di\modules\ActivityModule_BindSplashScreenActivity.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
import com....features.Main.splash_screen.SplashScreenActivity;
                                                                     ^
  symbol:   class SplashScreenActivity
  location: package com....features.Main.splash_screen
...\app\build\generated\source\kapt\stagingDebug\com\...\common\di\modules\ActivityModule_BindSplashScreenActivity.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
  public interface SplashScreenActivitySubcomponent extends AndroidInjector<SplashScreenActivity> {
                                                                            ^
  symbol:   class SplashScreenActivity
  location: class ActivityModule_BindSplashScreenActivity
...\app\build\generated\source\kapt\stagingDebug\com\...\common\di\modules\ActivityModule_BindSplashScreenActivity.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
    interface Factory extends AndroidInjector.Factory<SplashScreenActivity> {}
                                                      ^
  symbol:   class SplashScreenActivity
  location: interface SplashScreenActivitySubcomponent
...\app\build\generated\source\kapt\stagingDebug\com\...\common\di\components\DaggerAppComponent.java:217: error: cannot find symbol
        SplashScreenActivity arg0) {
        ^
  symbol:   class SplashScreenActivity
  location: class DaggerAppComponent.SplashScreenActivitySubcomponentFactory
...\app\build\generated\source\kapt\stagingDebug\com\...\common\di\components\DaggerAppComponent.java:224: error: cannot find symbol
    private final SplashScreenActivity arg0;
                  ^
  symbol:   class SplashScreenActivity
  location: class DaggerAppComponent.SplashScreenActivitySubcomponentImpl
...\app\build\generated\source\kapt\stagingDebug\com\...\common\di\components\DaggerAppComponent.java:226: error: cannot find symbol
    private SplashScreenActivitySubcomponentImpl(SplashScreenActivity arg0Param) {
                                                 ^
  symbol:   class SplashScreenActivity
  location: class DaggerAppComponent.SplashScreenActivitySubcomponentImpl
...\app\build\generated\source\kapt\stagingDebug\com\...\common\di\components\DaggerAppComponent.java:233: error: cannot find symbol
    private SplashScreenPresenter getSplashScreenPresenter() {
            ^
  symbol:   class SplashScreenPresenter
  location: class DaggerAppComponent.SplashScreenActivitySubcomponentImpl
...\app\build\generated\source\kapt\stagingDebug\com\...\common\di\components\DaggerAppComponent.java:237: error: cannot find symbol
    public void inject(SplashScreenActivity arg0) {
                       ^
  symbol:   class SplashScreenActivity
  location: class DaggerAppComponent.SplashScreenActivitySubcomponentImpl
...\app\build\generated\source\kapt\stagingDebug\com\...\common\di\components\DaggerAppComponent.java:240: error: cannot find symbol
    private SplashScreenActivity injectSplashScreenActivity(SplashScreenActivity instance) {
                                                            ^
  symbol:   class SplashScreenActivity
  location: class DaggerAppComponent.SplashScreenActivitySubcomponentImpl
...\app\build\generated\source\kapt\stagingDebug\com\...\common\di\components\DaggerAppComponent.java:240: error: cannot find symbol
    private SplashScreenActivity injectSplashScreenActivity(SplashScreenActivity instance) {
            ^
  symbol:   class SplashScreenActivity
  location: class DaggerAppComponent.SplashScreenActivitySubcomponentImpl
...\app\build\generated\source\kapt\stagingDebug\com\...\features\Main\splash_screen\SplashScreenActivity_MembersInjector.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
public final class SplashScreenActivity_MembersInjector implements MembersInjector<SplashScreenActivity> {
                                                                                   ^
  symbol: class SplashScreenActivity
...\app\build\generated\source\kapt\stagingDebug\com\...\features\Main\splash_screen\SplashScreenActivity_MembersInjector.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
  private final Provider<SplashScreenPresenter> splashScreenPresenterProvider;
                         ^
  symbol:   class SplashScreenPresenter
  location: class SplashScreenActivity_MembersInjector
...\app\build\generated\source\kapt\stagingDebug\com\...\features\Main\splash_screen\SplashScreenActivity_MembersInjector.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
      Provider<SplashScreenPresenter> splashScreenPresenterProvider) {
               ^
  symbol:   class SplashScreenPresenter
  location: class SplashScreenActivity_MembersInjector
...\app\build\generated\source\kapt\stagingDebug\com\...\features\Main\splash_screen\SplashScreenActivity_MembersInjector.java:48: error: cannot find symbol
      Provider<SplashScreenPresenter> splashScreenPresenterProvider) {
               ^
  symbol:   class SplashScreenPresenter
  location: class SplashScreenActivity_MembersInjector
...\app\build\generated\source\kapt\stagingDebug\com\...\features\Main\splash_screen\SplashScreenActivity_MembersInjector.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
  public static MembersInjector<SplashScreenActivity> create(
                                ^
  symbol:   class SplashScreenActivity
  location: class SplashScreenActivity_MembersInjector
...\app\build\generated\source\kapt\stagingDebug\com\...\features\Main\splash_screen\SplashScreenActivity_MembersInjector.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
  public void injectMembers(SplashScreenActivity instance) {
                            ^
  symbol:   class SplashScreenActivity
  location: class SplashScreenActivity_MembersInjector
...\app\build\generated\source\kapt\stagingDebug\com\...\features\Main\splash_screen\SplashScreenActivity_MembersInjector.java:61: error: cannot find symbol
  public static void injectSplashScreenPresenter(SplashScreenActivity instance,
                                                 ^
  symbol:   class SplashScreenActivity
  location: class SplashScreenActivity_MembersInjector
...\app\build\generated\source\kapt\stagingDebug\com\...\features\Main\splash_screen\SplashScreenActivity_MembersInjector.java:62: error: cannot find symbol
      SplashScreenPresenter splashScreenPresenter) {
      ^
  symbol:   class SplashScreenPresenter
  location: class SplashScreenActivity_MembersInjector
...\app\build\generated\source\kapt\stagingDebug\com\...\features\Main\splash_screen\SplashScreenPresenter_Factory.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
public final class SplashScreenPresenter_Factory implements Factory<SplashScreenPresenter> {
                                                                    ^
  symbol: class SplashScreenPresenter
...\app\build\generated\source\kapt\stagingDebug\com\...\features\Main\splash_screen\SplashScreenPresenter_Factory.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
  private final Provider<ISplashScreen> viewProvider;
                         ^
  symbol:   class ISplashScreen
  location: class SplashScreenPresenter_Factory
...\app\build\generated\source\kapt\stagingDebug\com\...\features\Main\splash_screen\SplashScreenPresenter_Factory.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
  public SplashScreenPresenter_Factory(Provider<ISplashScreen> viewProvider,
                                                ^
  symbol:   class ISplashScreen
  location: class SplashScreenPresenter_Factory
...\app\build\generated\source\kapt\stagingDebug\com\...\features\Main\splash_screen\SplashScreenPresenter_Factory.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
  public SplashScreenPresenter get() {
         ^
  symbol:   class SplashScreenPresenter
  location: class SplashScreenPresenter_Factory
...\app\build\generated\source\kapt\stagingDebug\com\...\features\Main\splash_screen\SplashScreenPresenter_Factory.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
  public static SplashScreenPresenter_Factory create(Provider<ISplashScreen> viewProvider,
                                                              ^
  symbol:   class ISplashScreen
  location: class SplashScreenPresenter_Factory
...\app\build\generated\source\kapt\stagingDebug\com\...\features\Main\splash_screen\SplashScreenPresenter_Factory.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
  public static SplashScreenPresenter newInstance(ISplashScreen view,
                                                  ^
  symbol:   class ISplashScreen
  location: class SplashScreenPresenter_Factory
...\app\build\generated\source\kapt\stagingDebug\com\...\features\Main\splash_screen\SplashScreenPresenter_Factory.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
  public static SplashScreenPresenter newInstance(ISplashScreen view,
                ^
  symbol:   class SplashScreenPresenter
  location: class SplashScreenPresenter_Factory
...\app\src\main\java\com\...\common\di\modules\ActivityModule.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
import com....features.Main.splash_screen.SplashModule;
                                                                     ^
  symbol:   class SplashModule
  location: package com....features.Main.splash_screen
...\app\src\main\java\com\...\common\di\modules\ActivityModule.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
import com....features.Main.splash_screen.SplashScreenActivity;
                                                                     ^
  symbol:   class SplashScreenActivity
  location: package com....features.Main.splash_screen
...\app\src\main\java\com\...\common\di\modules\ActivityModule.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
    abstract SplashScreenActivity bindSplashScreenActivity();
             ^
  symbol:   class SplashScreenActivity
  location: class ActivityModule
...\app\build\generated\source\kapt\stagingDebug\com\...\common\di\modules\ActivityModule_BindSplashScreenActivity.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
  @Subcomponent(modules = SplashModule.class)
                          ^
  symbol:   class SplashModule
  location: class ActivityModule_BindSplashScreenActivity
...\app\build\generated\source\kapt\stagingDebug\com\...\common\di\modules\ActivityModule_BindSplashScreenActivity.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
  @ClassKey(SplashScreenActivity.class)
            ^
  symbol:   class SplashScreenActivity
  location: class ActivityModule_BindSplashScreenActivity
...\app\src\main\java\com\...\common\di\modules\ActivityModule.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = SplashModule.class)
                                          ^
  symbol:   class SplashModule
  location: class ActivityModule
...\app\build\generated\source\kapt\stagingDebug\com\...\common\di\components\DaggerAppComponent.java:143: error: cannot find symbol
    return MapBuilder.<Class<?>, Provider<AndroidInjector.Factory<?>>>newMapBuilder(2).put(SplashScreenActivity.class, (Provider) splashScreenActivitySubcomponentFactoryProvider).put(MainActivity.class, (Provider) mainActivitySubcomponentFactoryProvider).build();}
                                                                                           ^
  symbol:   class SplashScreenActivity
  location: class DaggerAppComponent
...\app\build\generated\source\kapt\stagingDebug\com\...\common\di\components\DaggerAppComponent.java:234: error: cannot find symbol
      return new SplashScreenPresenter(arg0, DaggerAppComponent.this.providePresenterEnvironmentProvider.get());}
                 ^
  symbol:   class SplashScreenPresenter
  location: class DaggerAppComponent.SplashScreenActivitySubcomponentImpl
...\app\build\generated\source\kapt\stagingDebug\com\...\common\di\components\DaggerAppComponent.java:271: error: cannot find symbol
      return MapBuilder.<Class<?>, Provider<AndroidInjector.Factory<?>>>newMapBuilder(4).put(SplashScreenActivity.class, (Provider) DaggerAppComponent.this.splashScreenActivitySubcomponentFactoryProvider).put(MainActivity.class, (Provider) DaggerAppComponent.this.mainActivitySubcomponentFactoryProvider).put(CartFragment.class, (Provider) cartFragmentSubcomponentFactoryProvider).put(CategoriesFragment.class, (Provider) categoriesFragmentSubcomponentFactoryProvider).build();}
                                                                                             ^
  symbol:   class SplashScreenActivity
  location: class DaggerAppComponent.MainActivitySubcomponentImpl
...\app\build\generated\source\kapt\stagingDebug\com\...\features\Main\splash_screen\SplashScreenPresenter_Factory.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
    return new SplashScreenPresenter(viewProvider.get(), environmentProvider.get());
               ^
  symbol:   class SplashScreenPresenter
  location: class SplashScreenPresenter_Factory
...\app\build\generated\source\kapt\stagingDebug\com\...\features\Main\splash_screen\SplashScreenPresenter_Factory.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
    return new SplashScreenPresenter(view, environment);
               ^
  symbol:   class SplashScreenPresenter
  location: class SplashScreenPresenter_Factory
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
39 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileStagingDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 23s
50 actionable tasks: 9 executed, 41 up-to-date

Comment: Can you create a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and share it? (e.g. on GitHub/GitLab/Bitbucket, or a downloadable ZIP file)

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: What does work for me (kind of) is to rebuild the module. Annoying, but at least it works

Answer (score 0):

does your project use kapt?

If so, you can disable the cache of kapt.

Open your `build.gradle` file in the app module, and set the `useBuildCache` to false, and sync the Gradle.

Try to rebuild your code.

```kotlin
kapt {
    useBuildCache = false  
}
```

If everything goes fine, you can enable `useBuildCache` again.